# How can I solve this cakephp/cakephp 4.2.8 requires ext-intl PHP extension error on macOS?

Tags: macos, apache, php, open-source, mamp

With a MacBook Pro, I  use MAMP and I believe I already have intl PHP extension

[image]

When i am trying to update my cakephp project via composer i am getting this error

```
    - Root composer.json requires cakephp/cakephp ^4.2.8 -> satisfiable by cakephp/cakephp[4.2.8].
    - cakephp/cakephp 4.2.8 requires ext-intl * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's intl extension.
```

Then i checked which php and result is

```
which php 
/usr/bin/php
```

I tried to use composer.phar file but still same error.

How to change default php (mac os ) to MAMP?

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing php on a Mac then you should install homebrew. https://brew.sh/

Once installed you can run `brew install icu4c`. After this you can run `sudo pecl update-channels` and `sudo pecl install intl` to install the php-intl extension onto PHP shipped with Mac OS.